# Image at bottom of the page shouldn't be override by the content

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, background-image

I have an image at the bottom right of the web page. and i have a content table at the top of the page. If the content table size increases, it is displaying on the top of my image..

Is there a way to display the image all the time [ even with scroll bars ] even when the content table size increases.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: background-image:url('Background_Image.png');
  background-size: 100px 200px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: Sounds like you're image positioning is wrong. What do you use? (absolute, relative, etc..)

Comment: <body class="background"> <body>

Comment: set z-index css property to bottom-right image. i.e. z-index:5000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use z-index? The problem is once you have floated the image it is no longer influencing the layout of your page... text will display on top. Perhaps you could try to display: block; and place it in a div under your text, then have it float right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an image displayed at all times, irrespective of scrolling, it sounds like you are describing an image that is fixed.

You could use CSS code similar to this, where #myImage is the div that contains your non-moving image:

```
    #myImage
    {
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
    height:200px; 
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    }
```